# How to validate field using angular js with data annotation in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
public string Email { get; set; }
[RegularExpression(@"^((https?|ftp)://|(www|ftp)\.)[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)    ([/?].*)?$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid web address.")]
public string Web { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Company Name is required.")]
public string CompanyName { get; set; }
```

This is my code first validation in mvc.
I am using angular js please help me how to used angular js for validation.

Answer (score 0):

use like following code **in view**

```
<validated-input name="Web " display="Web " ng-model="model.Web" required>
<validated-input name="CompanyName" display="CompanyName" ng-model="model.CompanyName" required>
```

Comment: This is useful for required but how to used regular expression in  that.